# ComponentOne : C1NavigationList databinding with XMLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, iphone, xmldatasource, componentone

In the process of Iphone View ability for a shopping cart system, where i am trying to implement using the ComponentOne tools for Iphone in the products listing.For which i have identified C1NavigationList control for the same.

As i understand it is a Hierarchical data control, i am binding it to an XML DataSource, as i don't need any sub items but a collection of main items where the details as attributes of the XML node as below:

[image]

**Requirement:** I would like to define a layout in the C1Navigation list template and XPath bind the data as in the given screen grab above.

Given below is the code which i have tried to do but failed.It throws me the error :"*Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the...*."

What am i doing wrong?.Please advice me.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="/NewDataSet/_x0028__x0028"
```

DataFile="~/App_Data/Copy of Coffee____1__0__0_0_d.xml">

```
<C1NavigationList:C1NavigationList ID="C1NavigationList1" 
  runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" Text="XMLDataSource"   NavigationListType="RoundedCornersList" TrackItemsStructure="false">
```

<%# XPath("@item_smkt_desc")%>

Answer (score 1):

I would use a for loop to do this instead of XmlDataSource. Then you have more control over the UI anyways. I have used this method quite a bit successfully. Here is how I would write you code:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XElement xEle = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Copy of Coffee___1_0__0_0_d.xml"));
var items = from c in xEle.Elements("NewDataSet") select c;
foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement ele in items)
{
    C1.Web.iPhone.C1NavigationList.C1NavigationListItem li = new C1.Web.iPhone.C1NavigationList.C1NavigationListItem();
    li.Text = ele.Attribute("item_smkt_desc");
    C1NavigationList1.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I am still looking if any direct databinding is possible, asit being a data bound control.